# excel - cell format - comparing values

Tags: excel

I have the following requirement in Excel but now sure the formula I need to create:

Need to highlight rows in a different colour if:

- Value of Column 1 doesn't match value of Column 4 in the same row
- Value of Column 2 doesn't match value of Column 5 in the same row
- value of column 3 doesn't match value of column 6 in the same row

The values are not digits but characters.

Thanks,
Bruce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Gimp mentions, this is a conditional formatting issue (in case you didn't know what it is called, now you do :) ). Below is an example of how to accomplish what you want, but I would definitely suggest reading up on it since it comes in very handy:

[image]

Basically, you are setting up mini `IF` statements to check certain conditions. Also, note the `Stop if True` option - this means that if you hit a certain criteria and won't want to check any others, it will stop formatting and leave it with that color. Hope this helps get you started!